# Why cannot change the value for a specific column in a slice of pandas data frame using .loc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((10)), columns=list('A'))
df1['MATCHED'] = 0

df1

          A  MATCHED
0  0.424651        0
1  0.855567        0
2  0.983395        0
3  0.921866        0
4  0.001827        0
5  0.341491        0
6  0.055578        0
7  0.970564        0
8  0.078751        0
9  0.348055        0
```

Then I filter `df1`:

```
df1_slice = df1[df1['A'] <=0.4]
df1_slice
          A  MATCHED
4  0.001827        0
5  0.341491        0
6  0.055578        0
8  0.078751        0
9  0.348055        0
```

Now, I want to change the column MATCHED values for those rows in `df1_slice` :

```
df1.loc[df1_slice.index]['MATCHED']=1
```

I'd expect the MATCHED column changes in `df1` from 0 to 1, but it doesn't.

```
df1.loc[df1_slice.index]
          A  MATCHED
4  0.001827        0
5  0.341491        0
6  0.055578        0
8  0.078751        0
9  0.348055        0
```

Why they don't change and how to change this script so that they change to 1 in `df1`.

Comment: This is chained assignment. It has very unpredictable behaviour. More details here [No SettingWithCopyWarning for chained indexing when .loc or .iloc is first indexer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18752)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that using .loc throughout is the best way to (re-)assign to slices. In your example you use .loc only to slice on the index, not on the columns. This should do it (haven't tested):

```
df1.loc[df1_slice.index, 'MATCHED'] = 1
```